# Puppet install: timeout when retrieving certificate

Tags: linux, azure, puppet, puppetmaster

Trying to install the latest puppet enterprise (2023.0.0) per their guide on an Unbuntu 20.04 VM in Azure. I started with the out-of-the-box pe.conf. Install proceeds for awhile until I get some messages like:

```
2023-03-13T18:03:15.664+00:00 - [Notice]: Compiled catalog for [redacted].reddog.microsoft.com in environment enterprise in 0.33 seconds  
2023-03-13T18:08:16.307+00:00 - [Error]: Command exceeded timeout
2023-03-13T18:08:16.309+00:00 - [Error]: /Stage[main]/Pe_install::Prepare::Certificates/Exec[retrieve cert for [redacted].reddog.microsoft.com]/returns: change from 'notrun' to ['0'] failed: Command exceeded timeout  
2023-03-13T18:08:16.316+00:00 - [Notice]: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Pxp_agent::Service/Service[pxp-agent]: Dependency Exec[retrieve cert for [redacted].reddog.microsoft.com] has failures: true
```

From here, the install sputters and eventually dies with the message:

```
2023-03-13T18:08:16.600+00:00 [ERROR]: !! There were problems during the application of the installation catalog. !!
```

Seems like it's having trouble with a cert, but I'm not clear what's happening here. I know that Microsoft adds a "phony" DNS suffix of reddog.microsoft.com on all its VMs that doesn't resolve. Is this the problem? Unresolvable DNS entry?

I took a stab at modifying the pe.conf file to specify the "puppet_enterprise::puppet_master_host" value to a properly resolving DNS entry (that resolves to the machine itself), but that didn't help.

Would appreciate any puppet/linux experts' assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I solved it. In the installer conf.d/pe.conf file, there is a section that is commented out by default:

```
"pe_install::puppet_master_dnsaltnames": ["puppet"]
```

I uncommented this and also added my FQDN to the list, and then the install proceeded successfully.